# Fetch API with frontend Javascript returns CORS and 302 error

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, http-status-code-302

I am trying to fetch and API that has worked in the past for me, but now is returning:

```
[Error] Preflight response is not successful. Status code: 302
[Error] Fetch API cannot load http://api-im-trying-to-fetch due to access control checks.
[Error] Failed to load resource: Preflight response is not successful. Status code: 302 (states, line 0)
```

I tried disabling Cross-origin Restrinctions and adding information to the headers, like mode:'no-corse', but nothing worked.
I was wondering if it's something that has to do with the API and I can't do nothing about it.
Thank you!

```
const apiKey = 'secret-api';
const endpoint = 'url of api';

export const getAbortionInfo = async() => {
    try{
        const response = await fetch(endpoint, {
            headers: {
                'token': apiKey
            }
        });
            if(response.ok){
                const jsonResponse = await response.json();
                console.log(jsonResponse)
            }
            throw new Error('Resquest failed!')
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A [preflight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) request is sent when the browser needs permission (via CORS) from the server to make the real request.

You need to get the permission from the URL you want to request.

The CORS specification doesn't allow you to redirect somewhere else.

You need to make a request which doesn't cause the server to respond with a redirect. This could be as simple as changing the URL you are requesting from `https://example.com/api/foo` to `https://example.com/api/foo/`. Using the Network tab of your browser's developer tools should show you the redirect response and let you examine the `Location` response header to find out where the request is being redirected to.

---

Note that once you have solved the redirect problem, you will still require the server to send CORS response headers to provide permission for you to access it.

Using `mode: 'no-cors'` won't help. That tells the browser that you don't want to do anything which requires CORS permission and it should fail silently if it hits a CORS problem. Setting non-standard HTTP headers (such as `token`) requires CORS permission.